# How to remove a cell from a single row table?

Tags: reporting, odoo

What is the correct way to remove a single cell from a single row table based on a condition?

I have the following formula that is supposed to print "Great Client" if the word "Great" is located within the client name:

```
(so.partner_id.name.find('Great') > 0) and "Great Client" or removeParentNode('td')
```

It works fine when the condition is met, but I get an error message when it isn't, i.e. when it hits the removeParentNode('td'):

```
(<type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>, AssertionError(), <traceback object at 0x7fdae4b7e248>)
```

How is it possible to remove a single cell from a single row table?

Comment: I think openerp not allowed to remove td :(

Comment: For this type report you have to create dynamic report, you can get example from survey moduel

Comment: Your information is contradictory. If OpenERP can't do it, why would I search for an example??? FYI, OpenERP does this exactly as running my own dynamic report works fine from my windows server, but the same report returns the error message I stated in my message when ran from the Ubuntu server, even though the client computer is exactly the same. Therefore, it has to come from the interpretation on the Ubuntu server!